# How to set gunicorn to find a flask application?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

Please configure gunicorn to find a flask application.
I guess application name is defined inside create_function() hides the application from run.py; however, I don't know how to fix it. 
Here is the error when to run gunicorn with the application:

```
  1 (venv) MacPro:11a toshio$ gunicorn run:app
  2 [2015-12-27 15:10:45 +0900] [83437] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.1
  3 [2015-12-27 15:10:45 +0900] [83437] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (83437)
  4 [2015-12-27 15:10:45 +0900] [83437] [INFO] Using worker: sync
  5 [2015-12-27 15:10:45 +0900] [83440] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 83440
  6 Failed to find application: 'run'
  7 [2015-12-27 15:10:51 +0900] [83440] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 83440)
  8 [2015-12-27 15:10:52 +0900] [83437] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
  9 [2015-12-27 15:10:52 +0900] [83437] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
 10 (venv) MacPro:11a toshio$
```

The application structure is following:

```
  1 ├── app
  2 │   ├── __init__.py
  3 │   ├── main
  4 │   │   ├── __init__.py
  5 │   │   ├── forms.py
  6 │   │   └── routes.py
  7 │   ├── models.py
  8 │   ├── static
  9 │   │   ├── js
 10 │   │   ├── css
 11 │   │   ├── pdf
 12 │   └── templates
 13 │       ├── base.html
 14 │       ├── index.html
 15 │       ├── login.html
 16 ├── config
 17 │   └── development.py
 18 ├── data-dev.sqlite3
 19 ├── run.py
```

The package constructer **app/__init__.py** code:

```
  1 import os
  2 import subprocess
  3 import imghdr
  4 from datetime import datetime
  5 from flask import Flask, render_template, session, g, redirect, url_for, request
  6 from flask.ext.script import Manager
  7 from flask.ext.wtf import Form
  8 from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
  9 from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, ValidationError, PasswordField, BooleanField
 10 from wtforms.validators import Required, Length
 11 from werkzeug import secure_filename
 12 from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
 13 from flask_wtf.file import FileField
 14 from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
 15 from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
 16 from flask.ext.login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, logout_user, login_required

 18 bootstrap = Bootstrap()
 19 db = SQLAlchemy()
 20 lm = LoginManager()
 21 lm.login_view = 'main.login'
 22 
 23 def create_app(config_name):
 24     """ Create an application instance """
 25     app = Flask(__name__, static_folder = 'static')
 26 
 27     # import configration
 28     cfg = os.path.join( os.getcwd(), 'config', config_name + '.py' )
 29     app.config.from_pyfile(cfg)
 30 
 31     # initialize extenstions
 32     bootstrap.init_app(app)
 33     db.init_app(app)
 34     lm.init_app(app)
 35 
 36     # import blueprints
 37     from .main import main as main_blueprint
 38     app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)
 39 
 40     return app
```

Lastly **run.py** is follwing:

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/env python
  2 from app import create_app, db
  3 from app.models import User, Book
  4 
  5 
  6 if __name__ == '__main__':
  7     app = create_app('development')
  8     with app.app_context():
  9         db.create_all()
 10         if User.query.filter_by(username='somebody').first() is None:
 11             User.register('somebody', 'abc')
 12     app.run()
```

Comment: `gunicorn app:run` might work as well.

Answer (score 5):

Try to run gunicorn from the command line like this:

```
gunicorn 'app:create_app("development")'
```

Comment: What a quick answer! It works, awsome!!!  Add on that, how should put the rest of the code in run.py; say, put db.create_all() in create_app() ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `wsgi.py` file to your project and add next lines to it:

```
from app import create_app

application = create_app('development')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

Save and close your new file, go to your app folder and run:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems it does not work.  I've got the same error like this: `(venv) MacPro:11a toshio$ gunicorn  --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi
[2015-12-27 17:23:58 +0900] [84005] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.1
[2015-12-27 17:23:58 +0900] [84005] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (84005)
[2015-12-27 17:23:58 +0900] [84005] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2015-12-27 17:23:59 +0900] [84008] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 84008
Failed to find application: 'wsgi' `

Comment: @Toshio Do you run it from your project  folder ? Also, note that wsgi.py should be placed in your project folder.

Comment: Yes, I do.  In my project folder I have these:  `Dockerfile              app                     doc_data.txt            run-flask.py            unicorn_key.pem
README                  config                  gunicorn.err            run.py                  wsgi.py
__pycache__             data-dev.sqlite3        requirements.txt        tree.log

 ` @Toshio

Comment: what operation system do you use? Do you have `python-dev` lib? Ensure that you are running gunicorn which belongs to your virtualenv (use command `which gunicorn`).

Comment: Try to use full dotted path as name of wsgi application as `path.to.wsgi` instead of simply passing `wsgi` that could do the trick...

Comment: Mac OS.X10.10.5, no python-dev exist.  It says:  `(venv) MacPro:11a toshio$ sudo pip install python-dev
Password:
Downloading/unpacking python-dev
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python-dev
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for python-dev
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/toshio/.pip/pip.log`

Comment: gunicorn belongs to my venv.   I don't understand path.to.wsgi?

Comment: @Toshio Would back to your question and try to update my answer. Problem would be fixed after passing wsgi.py to gunicorn correclty...

Comment: You need to move the `application = create_app` line outside the if.

Comment: @dirn thanks, answer updated according to your comment